# Antiderivative of $\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}$

Tags: integration

Is there a simple antiderivative of $\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}, \quad n \in \mathbb{N}$?

This functions seems realy easy, but if I try the product rule, I get a worse fraction.

Comment: If $n$ is a positive integer, your fraction can be simplified.

Comment: Hint: $1-x^n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ has a root $x=1$. Now what does that tell you? Think in terms of factorization.

Comment: There is no simple form without either a $\sum_{i=0}^n$ or a ${}+\cdots+{}$ (or something very like those) in it. At least as far as I can tell from looking at [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Int%281-x%5En%29%2F%281-x%29dx).

Comment: Indeed, $n$ is positive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the fact that
$$x^n-1 = (x-1)(1+x+x^2+...+x^{n-1})$$
So
$$\int \frac{1-x^n}{1-x} dx= \int (1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^{n-1})dx$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: what is $(1-x)(1+x+x^2+...+x^{n-1})$?