# Is it possible to simplify this version of a geometric series? $f(x) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{x^k}{k}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

**Is it possible to simplify this series?**

$$
f(x) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{x^k}{k}
$$

If I derive it, I get the geometric series

$$
f'(x) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n x^{k-1} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} x^{k} = \frac{1-x^n}{1-x}
$$

But this seems to lead to nothing as

$$
f(x) = \int \frac{1-x^n}{1-x} dx
$$

can't expressed simpler as a comment in my previous question [Antiderivative of $\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3932971/antiderivative-of-frac1-xn1-x?noredirect=1#comment8110820_3932971) mentioned.

I know, that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int \frac{1-x^n}{1-x} dx = -\ln{(|x-1|)}, \quad -1 < x < 1$

But what about without these restrictions of $n$ and $x$?

Comment: Well, I did already (second equation).

Comment: There's no hope for a really simple closed form for this function, because such a closed form would imply a really simple closed form for $f(1) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} = H_n$, the harmonic number (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

Answer (score 1):

Beside the  incomplete Beta function, you also have
$$f(x) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{x^k}{k}=-x^{n+1}\, \Phi (x,1,n+1)-\log (1-x)$$ where appears the Lerch transcendent function.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica tells me it is
$$ f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{x^k}{k} = \int\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}\ \mathrm{d}x =  -\mathrm{B}(x,1+n,0) - \ln(1 - x),$$
where $\mathrm{B}(x,a,b)$ is the [incomplete Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function?oldformat=true#Incomplete_beta_function). Not sure if that satisfies you. Also not sure what you mean by simplifying.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But sadly thats not what I expected. The incomplete beta functions doesn't seem to be "simple". I mean expressions like $\frac{1}{1-x}$ or something with logarithm. Because all the other derivatives of the geometric series can be simplified easy, but the antiderivative, too?

Comment: No. If there's no closed form there's no closed form. Basically the function is defined by the integral.